# Finding the largest area of equal numbers in matrix java

Tags: java, algorithm, matrix, tree

I have a task.I need to find the biggest area with equal numbers(e.g. neighbours by row or column). The program that i made works fine,but the problem is that if i have the following matrix:

```
{ 1, 3, 2, 2, 2, 4 } 
{ 3, 1, 3, 2, 4, 4 }
{ 4, 3, 1, 2, 3, 3 }  
{ 4, 3, 1, 3, 3, 1 }  
{ 4, 3, 3, 3, 1, 1 }
```

The program will print 10.Okay maybe some of you may say that it's because i add 1 to the final result,yeah that's true but if i don't add 1 ,and if the number at position [1][1] was 3 instead of 1 ,i would get 12 witch is wrong,so that`s why i add 1.So my question is do you have any suggestions about optimazing the algorithm..if yes,i would be very thankful to hear them :)..

`Here is my code:`

```
protected  int counter = 0;
    protected  int max = 1;
    protected enum eState {
        Vi,
        InPr,
        Unvi
    };

    public void recNodeMatrix(int i, int j, eState st[][],int [][]matr,int n,int k) {

        st[i][j] = eState.InPr;

        for (int r = 0; r < n; r++) {
            for (int c = 0; c < k; c++) {
                if ((matr[i][j] == matr[r][c]) 
                        && ((((i+j) - (r + c)) == 1) || (((i+j) - (r + c)) == -1))
                        && ((st[r][c] == eState.Unvi))) { 
                    counter++;
                    recNodeMatrix(r, c, st,matr,n,k); 
                }
            }
        }
        st[i][j] = eState.Vi;
    }


    public  void Zad17() {

        int n=5,k=6;
        eState st[][] = new eState[n][k];

        int[][] matr = new int[][] {
                { 1, 3, 2, 2, 2, 4 },
                { 3, 1, 3, 2, 4, 4 },
                { 4, 3, 1, 2, 3, 3 },
                { 4, 3, 1, 3, 3, 1 },
                { 4, 3, 3, 3, 1, 1 } };



        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < k; j++) {
                st[i][j] = eState.Unvi;
            }
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < k; j++) {
                if(st[i][j] == eState.Unvi) {
                    recNodeMatrix(i, j, st,matr,n,k);
                    if(max<counter)
                        max=counter;
                    counter =0;
                }
            }
        }


        System.out.print(max+1);
    }
```

Comment: Start at any cell and flood-fill the area around it, marking the cells you visit as you go along (e.g. by a boolean flag or reversing the sign of the cell), and obviously ignoring cells which have already been visited or have a different number.

Comment: @meowgoesthedog's comment provides the correct answer. However, I just want to add that your code is awfully slow because each time you scan the ENTIRE grid to find neighboring cells, while you should actually only check the 4 (or 8) neighboring cell. Your complexity is **O(N^2 . K^2)**, while the mentioned optimization makes it **O(N . K)**.

Comment: This is an example of how Depth First Search could help ( the previous comments' flood-fill means that in asense ) Start with a cell ( i,  j ) search for equal valued cells by doing dfs and each time you do it, record the maximum number of cells that you covered.

Answer (score 1):

Probably the best way to solve this problem is with a union-find data structure: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disjoint-set_data_structure

Initially, each cell is its own set, and then you merge the sets for every pair of adjacent cells that have equal numbers in them.

When you're done, the answer is the size of the biggest set.  Since you have to keep track of the set sizes anyway, use union-by-size instead of union-by-rank.

Applying a bit of cleverness, you can implement the union-find with just an array of N*K integers -- one for each cell.  Each integer is either the index of the parent set or -size for roots.

This solves the problem in about linear time, and will probably be faster in practice than flood-fill solutions using a similar amount of memory.